# Rust "this parameter and the return type are declared with different lifetimes"

Tags: rust

I'm using the smol library from Rust. None of the other answers to this question helped.

The [smol's Executor::spawn()](https://docs.rs/smol/0.4.3/smol/struct.Executor.html#method.spawn) is declared like so:

```rust
    pub fn spawn<T: Send + 'a>(&self, future: impl Future<Output = T> + Send + 'a) -> Task<T> {
```

Now I have a function and want to call spawn recursively like so:

```rust
async fn start(executor: &Executor<'_>) {
    let server_task = executor.spawn(async {
        executor.spawn(async { println!("hello"); }).await;
    });
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```rust
9  | async fn start(executor: &Executor<'_>) {
   |                           ------------  -
   |                           |
   |                           this parameter and the return type are declared with different lifetimes...
...
18 |     let server_task = executor.spawn(async {
   |                                ^^^^^ ...but data from `executor` is returned here
```

How can I resolve this error? I'm very confused.

Comment: The docs you link to are outdated. Looks like the method in the latest version [uses the struct's lifetime](https://docs.rs/smol/1.2.5/smol/struct.Executor.html#method.spawn), which in this case is `'_`.

Comment: Thanks! This makes it even more confusing!

Answer (score 0):

```
use {
    smol::{block_on, Executor},
    std::sync::Arc,
};

// --

fn main() {
    let ex = Arc::new(Executor::new());
    block_on(ex.run(start(ex.clone())));
}

async fn start(executor: Arc<Executor<'_>>) {
    let ex2 = executor.clone();
    let server_task = executor.spawn(async move {
        let t = ex2.spawn(async {
            println!("hello");
        });
        t.await;
    });
    server_task.await;
}
```